# Apple Mobile Product Type constants such as "Watch4,4"

Tags: ios, apple-watch

When consuming Apple Health data we need to do some parsing of Product Type strings such as

- "iPhone12,3"
- "Watch4,4"

Are these maintained in the iOS SDK? I don't want to maintain my own list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to maintain a list or use a list like [this](https://gist.github.com/adamawolf/3048717) which updates often.

Another good alternative is [DeviceKit](https://github.com/devicekit/DeviceKit). But no sdk gives the list of devices.